# jQuery use datepicker inside tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, datepicker

i have a main page with tabs
main.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/datepicker-it.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
}); 
</script>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="page1.php">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.php">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.php and page2.php contains at the beginning the following code in order to display the datepicker on the input with classes="datepicker"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>    
$(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "it" ] );
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });
});
```

but after loading tab i get this error and date datepicker does not work

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting to load jQuery UI on page1 and page2.

Comment: by adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/datepicker-it.js"></script> i get the following errors: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
VM96:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined